# Highcharts Pie chart data Format via php

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

Am using Highcharts for pie chart. Below is the JS code for it :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var chart;

var graphData = $("#graphContentdata").val();
console.log(graphData);
var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'graphContainer',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'SOV'
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
           data: []
        }]
    }

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    chart.series[0].setData("["+graphData+"]");

 });
```

And PHP Code for generating the Data :

```
foreach ($sumArray as $key=>$value)
    {
        $sumArray[$key] = array_sum($value);
        $percent = (number_format(($sumArray[$key]/$sovGrandTotal)*100,2));

        $data[] =  "['$key', $percent]";            
    }
    $data = join(",", $data);

?>               
  <input type='hidden' id='graphContentdata' value="<?php echo $data; ?>">
```

The Data format Am getting is :

```
['www.quora.com', 0.23],['www.slideshare.net', 0.25],['me', 99.52]
```

Problem is :

```
chart.series[0].setData("["+graphData+"]");
```

not creating graph, but if i copy paste the value from console at palce of `graphData` variable, its working like:

```
chart.series[0].setData([['www.quora.com', 0.23],['www.slideshare.net', 0.25],['me', 99.52]]);
```

is working.

What's the mistake am doing here???

Comment: Did you try to put echo json_encode($data); ? Actually your data is an php array which has no value in js. Anyway, writting that in the value of the input is not the best way.

Comment: I tried echo json_encode($data); but it gives empty string ...

Comment: any other formats to pass it to pie chart data???
[me] = 99.52
[www.quora.com] = 0.23
[www.slideshare.net] = 0.25

Comment: Yes, the error is because of what you get from input value looks like an array but actually is a sample string.

Comment: even i tried to pass as JSON value like : {"www.quora.com":0.23,"www.slideshare.net":0.25,"me":99.52}... But that is also not working

Comment: In case when you use JSON you should have construciton: 
{name: "www.quora.com", y: 0.23 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your are passing your data as a String when you are using

```
chart.series[0].setData("["+graphData+"]");
```

You need to [set your data as an Array](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData%28%29). You could do that by converting your String using [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```
chart.series[0].setData(eval("["+graphData+"]"));
```

You could also [use jQuery to convert your String to JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), but in that case you [must use double quotes](http://json.org/) to open and close Strings:

```
$.parseJSON("[[\"www.quora.com\", 0.23],[\"www.slideshare.net\", 0.25],[\"me\", 99.52]]");
```